# How i can add space in Yii2 kartik gridview?

Tags: yii2, kartik-v

I'm using Yii2 kartik gridview for displaying orders, i need to add CURRENCY field like

AED 10 but now its showing without space like AED10

Here is my code :

```
 [
        'class' => 'kartik\grid\DataColumn',
        'attribute' => 'sub_total',
        'hAlign' => 'right',
        'vAlign' => 'middle',
        'format' => ['AED', $currency],
        'width' => '12%',
        'pageSummary' => true
    ]
```

I need space between currency code and price

Comment: Does `'format' => ['AED ', $currency],` not working?

Comment: Formatting currency value failed: 1 Number formatting failed: U_ILLEGAL_ARGUMENT_ERROR

Comment: Append space to `' ' .$currency` then :)

Comment: I tried that also, it also not working

Comment: How about `'format' => ['AED&nbsp;', $currency]`?

Comment: When I use formatter it's like this `'format' => ['currency', 'AED']` and there is a space already